# any way to get back PEAR DB functionality from 4 years ago?

Tags: php, database, authentication, pear

I have an application built in 2007 that makes extensive use of PEAR's AUTH and DB packages. It had been mothballed but out again now. Since those packages are not available and pear has completely changed, it no longer works in my system.

Outside of rewriting the entire software, is there anyway to get the previous functionality of DB & AUTH packages?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can find what version number(s) you were running, yes, you can get an old copy. Any ideas what they were? Furthermore, why do you no longer have those packages - are they not in your version control?

Comment: The problem is it conflicts with PHP 5.3, the only option for php I have

Comment: OKay. Here's the info from pear: CVS: $Id: PEAR.php,v 1.101 2006/04/25 02:41:03. Now, how do I install the old version when the only available go-pear.php conflicts with php 5.3? Thanks, I really do want to use this and appreciate your/anyone's help

Comment: That's the version number of PEAR, I think. You'll need the version numbers of the actual libraries you wish to use - or you could try the latest versions that still work for your target version of PHP.

Comment: Auth.php,v 1.4 2006/03/02. AND. MDB2.php,v 1.292 2007/04/25 09:31:01

Comment: Right, so download this: [Pear Auth 1.4](http://pear.php.net/package/Auth/download/1.4.0)? and ditto for PEAR DB?

Comment: I thought there was some hidden file that controlled access and accessibility. Is all I have to do is download them, throw them in a directory and access that directory?

Comment: The version of your software and the specification of your access control (who can access what) are two completely different things, and you were asking about the first one. Download them, and if you save them in their original locations, your old application should employ them in its usual way. You will need to reconstruct your user accounts and access rules, which I would guess are stored in the database.

Comment: _Is all I have to do is download them, throw them in a directory and access that directory?_ - no, probably not. Their access control is likely to be far more complicated than that. As I say, the access restrictions are probably stored in a table - maybe if you read the source code of your application, it will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing some investigative work yourself, you could look at the changelog pages for both of those packages - at http://pear.php.net/package/Auth/download/All and http://pear.php.net/package/DB/download/All to determine which version of these packages you had installed and used when you developed your application.

Once you've confirmed and installed the specific versions of these packages that you need, you might want to consider writing what's called a "[PEAR Meta Package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.dependencytracking.php)" and committing it to your version control system so that you can ensure these specific packages can be easily installed again (on other servers, whichever) with minimum hassle.

Comment: Thanks kguest. So I would look at my version that I had installed, if I can find it, and match it against the changelog at pear. Then get the version of the pear packages and installer and use it, somehow figure out how to make it work with PHP5.3 because of deprecated functions, and use that?

Comment: Yes. Also if they are just deprecated functions, and not removed ones, then you should have no problems as such apart from php informing you that they are deprecated.